# Single word to use instead of "can't" or "won't"

Tags: single-word-requests, programming

I'm looking for a single word to use instead of *can't* or *won't*.

(Single also meaning no hyphenation or conjunctions/contractions. The differences between the words in regard to *being unable to* vs. *being unwilling to* can be ignored)

**Edit:** Some background into this question, when writing Unit Tests in C# I have found it very easy to misread method names that differ solely based on Can vs Cannot. Since many times a unit test will exist with both the pro and contra side. Contractions aren't acceptable for the fact ' is not an allowed character in a method name.

Comment: Do you want one word to replace each of "can't" AND "won't" or are you looking for a single word to replace "can't / won't"?

Comment: Er, 'cannot' ? (According to Webster 1913)

Comment: How about No. Can you use the desired word in a sentence?

Comment: @Chris: why exactly do you want a single word?  Just curiosity, or is there some practical reason?

Comment: Maybe there are languages with a single word for both voluntary and involuntary non-compliance, but I'd be surprised if English is one. And why would we want it? We get enough trouble even sticking with just our two standard words. How many times have we all had to face the rejoinder "You mean you can't, or you *won't*?"

Comment: C# test method names, can't use ' in names, and I find methods that differentiate solely by can vs can not are too hard to distinguish

Comment: @Chris: Please put the C# bit in the description. Knowing how you will be using the word helps us find the best ones. :)

Comment: 'Fail' can be a substitute for can't, can't it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I *refuse* works in place of I *won't*.

Comment: Refuse is a good one! Even better since it has accepts as it's antonym and both words are very fitting for programming.

Comment: Some synonyms: Resist, Deny

Comment: Deny is also a very good word here.

Answer (score 3):

**Cannot?**  Or are you counting that as a compound word?

If you won’t take that, then I’m unable to suggest another.  It would be unfeasible for a language to have one-word synonyms for every concept; I suspect it’s impossible to find another for *cannot*/*can’t*/*won’t* in English.

Answer (score 1):

can't can be replaced with "unable" depending on context. Though, to be fair, this often requires words to be added elsewhere in the sentence.

Example:

I can't do that. -> I am unable to do that.

**EDIT**: Just saw that you put "unable" in the question. Oh well. CW'd it just in case anyone finds it useful.